# backface-visibility causing odd text aliasing

Tags: css

I'm noticing a difference in the anti-aliasing in Webkit for text within an element that uses `backface-visibility`. From the image (below) the top text is from a paragraph outside the noted area - and the other, inside (the lower-text is skinnier). I believe I've traced the issue down to `.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}` The backface-visibility seems to be messing with text-rendering. I've tried a few ways to "re-add" what the rest of the site has, but no such luck as of yet (for example - using the suggestions [here](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing/)). Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image: Flex Slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backface-visibility` has caused major problems and issues for me before, like with google-maps and with forms.

Best bet is to force it to be disabled on problematic elements.

```
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: none !important;}
```

Comment: Appreciate the input - yup another dev just confirmed this is Webkit being naughty, so I'll steer clear for now. Thanks!